# Jenkins not detect npm errors

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have node.js app and when I build with jenkins there are some error in npm in Test stage but Jenkins show final result as Success.

Here is my Jenkinsfile:
https://github.com/vforv/hapi-seneca-ts/blob/master/Jenkinsfile

> Here is log from Jenkins: npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a
>   problem with npm itself npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not
>   being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   /home/master/Downloads/workspace/vforv_hapi-seneca-ts_master-NY435NVPNBGYF7GSPZ5PYV4PUKK34TOM7BHZ2B4NOLDFO67XBNUQ/npm-debug.log
>   vforv_hapi-seneca-ts_master-NY435NVPNBGYF7GSPZ5PYV4PUKK34TOM7BHZ2B4NOLDFO67XBNUQ tested... npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-87-generic npm ERR! argv
>   "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "test"

What can be a problem?

Comment: what are contents of the `./system/fuge/test.sh` script in the Test stage that is causing the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/vforv/hapi-seneca-ts/blob/master/system/fuge/test.sh

Comment: It is not problem problem is why Jenkins not detect errors...

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the script in question (`./system/fuge/test.sh`) is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ..
for d in `ls` ; do

    if ! [ $d == 'system' ] && ! [ $d == 'npm-debug.log' ] && ! [ $d == 'README.md' ] && ! [ $d == 'monitor' ] && ! [ $d == 'dist' ] && ! [ $d == 'bases-service' ] && ! [ $d == 'repl' ]; then
        cd $d
        npm test
        echo "$d tested..."
        cd ..
    fi

done
```

The problem is a command in there (`npm test`) is failing but the *last* command in there is succeeding, so the script succeeds (so your build succeeds). Generally you want your build to fail if anything goes wrong in a script. You can accomplish that by telling the script not to tolerate any bad exit codes, by setting errexit like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

cd ..
for d in `ls` ; do

    if ! [ $d == 'system' ] && ! [ $d == 'npm-debug.log' ] && ! [ $d == 'README.md' ] && ! [ $d == 'monitor' ] && ! [ $d == 'dist' ] && ! [ $d == 'bases-service' ] && ! [ $d == 'repl' ]; then
        cd $d
        npm test
        echo "$d tested..."
        cd ..
    fi

done
```

Comment: How can I put it on global level for each script?

Comment: I think you're asking if you can avoid setting errexit in each script but still have the scripts act like it was set. No, you can't. :( You have to write each script in such a way that it returns a bad exit code when something bad happens.

Comment: please accept this if it answered your question. :)